# Hodge-Index Theorem for $\mathbb{C}P^2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

I'm trying to understand the Hodge-Index Theorem at the moment. What does it say explicitly for the case of $\mathbb{CP}^2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That the inner product on $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^2)$ has signature $(1,0)$.

Comment: .... and for the complex Grassamnnian Gr(n,k)?

Comment: Don't have time to do G(k,n) in general. Here's a small example: 
H^4(G(2,4)) is spanned by two Schubert classes: X:=[20] and Y:=[11]. 
The pairing on them has matrix ((0,1),(1,0)). Taking omega to be the 
chern class of the standard Plucker embedding,  
omega^2 H^0 is spanned by X+Y.  Also, omega H^1 is spanned by X+Y. 
The statement should be that the pairing is positive definite on 
omega^2 H^0 and negative definite on the orthogonal complement 
of omega H^1 (namely, X-Y). I think I might have gotten some of the signs
wrong in my previous write up of this; I'll check later.

Comment: @John: it might be a good idea to post another question -- more people will be able to answer that way.